# Update android app from code

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play, auto-update

I have an application on the play store. I am already checking if the version on the play store is different from the one I have installed, now, if this versions are different I need to trigger an update of the app. I know I can start an intent which will take me to the play store with my application in which will appear the update button: 
`startActivity(new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.novtory.provider") ));`

but I want to know if I can make the update automatically, without the user having to press the update button.

Comment: If they downloaded the app from the Play Store then the Play Store itself should update the app automatically.  Unless you are requesting more permissions then the user needs to approve the update.

Comment: As far as I know (i'm actually not sure) this update It's not made immediately when the application is updated, that's why I need to check it when the application opens and if its outdated to force update.

Comment: This is a feature in the play store.  If the user decides they don't want to auto-update, you shouldn't force them to.  If your app won't work without an update, you need to spend more effort on backwards compatibility.

Comment: @user3927659  It's not immediate, but it will eventually happen.  That is unless the user disabled auto-update as said, else your current approach will have to do. It is bad practice to force an update on the user unless it is critical however.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to do if you want to have your app update automatically.

**Download automatically**

This behavior depends on the user setting on Google play since your app will be updated from Google play. If the user enable automatically update for your app, it will download it when there is a new update detected. After download it, Google play will do the automatic installation thing described in following.

**Automatic installation**

This will install the app silently on the background without the user confirm `Install/Update` button. Google play can do this, but other third-party app have no way to do the silent installation.

As a result, as a regular app in Android, you can't make your app update automatically without user pressing `Update` button.